# accessing jsp files variable in tag files

Tags: java, jsp

I am new to JSP and was reading some docs regarding jsp tag and jsp files. I am using custom JSP tags in JSP files .I created a JSP file called demo.jsp and  custom tags file called tagsDemo.tag . I wanted to ask if it is possible to access the jsp objects/variables present in demo.jsp to use in tag file called tagsDemo.tag.

For example:
demo.jsp

```
...
<%a taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="t"%>

<c:set var="id" value="48848"></c:set>
...
```

I wanted to use this id variable in tag file. can we use it directly  like this `${id}` in tagsDemo.tag file ??

Comment: You need to define your custom tag to accept parameters.  Then in your JSP, you pass in the variable to the custom tag.

Comment: Yes use parameters. Directly referencing the variable is a bad idea because it would make the tag hard to reuse.  The point of tags is to be reusable.